# Insert data with CodeIgniter Active Records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

My question is about inserting data with CodeIgniter Active record. There's an example on the guide to insert data with array:

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

I wonder if there is some other way to insert the active record data, For example in in similar syntax:

```
    $this -> db -> select (*);
    $this -> db -> from ('users');
    $this -> db -> where('id', $id);
    $this -> db -> limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `set()` method.

According to CI documentation, you may use following syntax:

```
$this->db->set('name', $name);
$this->db->insert('mytable');
```

which will produce following query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('{$name}')
```

Hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Comment: once you insert the record ... what do you return from the Model to indicate that a record was successfully inserted?  thanks

Comment: @b_dubb You can use insert_id() helper method. Check the docs page for details: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

```
**its very simple just follow the following steps**<br>
**first prepare a dabase in mysql**<br>
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 02, 2013 at 03:48 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.27
-- PHP Version: 5.4.7

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `persons`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `person`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `person_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1728 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `person`
--

INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `person_name`, `person_address`) VALUES
(1726, 'soma', 'goma'),
(1727, 'roma', 'toma');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
<br>


**Open Codeigniter and make the follwoing changes in the following files**<br>

**make changes in autoload.php**<br>

**it is located  at**<br>

**C:\xampp\htdocs\CI_person\application\config**<br>

  from 

**$autoload['libraries'] = array('');** to
**$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');**$config['base_url']<br>

make changes in config.php 


**it is located  at**<br>

**C:\xampp\htdocs\CI_person\application\config**<br>


$config['base_url'] = ''; to

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';

make changes in database.php 


**it is located  at**<br>

**C:\xampp\htdocs\CI_person\application\config**<br>


$db['default']['hostname'] = '';<br>
$db['default']['username'] = '';<br>
$db['default']['password'] = '';<br>
$db['default']['database'] = '';<br>
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';<br>

to<br>
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';<br>
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';<br>
$db['default']['password'] = '';<br>
$db['default']['database'] = 'persons';<br>
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';<br>


now open the views folder located at<br>

**C:\xampp\htdocs\CI_person\application**<br>
**Create a view persons.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI_person\application\views**


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
function clicked()
{
alert("You clicked");
document.getElementById('check').value='I';

}
</script>

<form id="entry" name="entry"  method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="check" id="check" value="">
Person Name 
  <input type="text" name="person_name" id="person_name" />
  <br />
  Person Address
  <input type="text" name="person_address" id="person_address" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" onClick="clicked()">
<table  cellpadding="2px" width="600px"  border="2">
        <?php
            foreach ($persons as $person){
                $id = $person['id'];
                $name = $person['person_name'];
                $address = $person['person_address'];

        ?>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $address; ?><br /> </td>



        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
    </html>

**create controller named persons.php in Controller folder**<br>



<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Persons extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Person_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {       

         $person_name = $this->input->post('person_name');
         $person_address = $this->input->post('person_address');
         $check= $this->input->post('check');

    if  ($check=="") 
    {
        $this->data['persons'] = $this->Person_model->get_all();
        $this->load->view('persons', $this->data);
    }
    if  ($check=="I") 
    {

         /*$this->load->model('Person_model');
         $this->Person_model->insert_to_db($this->input->post('person_name'),$this->input->post('person_address'));
         */

         $this->Person_model->person_name = $person_name;
         $this->Person_model->person_address =$person_address;
         $this->Person_model->insert_into_db();
         $this->data['persons'] = $this->Person_model->get_all();
         $this->load->view('persons', $this->data);


    }


    }







}


**now create model as defined below in Models folder**<br>
<?php
class Person_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $person_name;
    public $person_address;
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function get_all()
    {
    $this->db->select('id,person_name,person_address');
    $query= $this->db->get('person');
    return $query->result_array();  
    }

    function insert_into_db()
    {

      $f1 = $this->person_name;
      $f2 = $this->person_address;

     $this->db->query("INSERT INTO person(person_name,person_address) VALUES('$f1','$f2')"); 

    }




}




?>

**Save all and run**
```

Comment: I would find this to be a rather cumbersome answer to follow.  In the future, I would suggest better formatting:  text explanations with separate code blocks around each.  More clarity, easier to copy/paste code when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Other way of inserting data in Codeigniter

```
    $query = $this->db->query('YOUR SQL QUERY');
```

or

```
   $this->db->set('name', $name);
   $this->db->insert('mytable');  // Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (`name`) VALUES ('{$name}')
```

Hopefully it can help you.